# ArangoDB anonymous graph traversal

Tags: graph, arangodb, graph-traversal

I am planing to use ArangoDB and I am faced with a problem I don't know how to solve. I would like to do simple traversals but in my case but there are two requirements that I don't know how to solve:

1. I will not know in advance the type of vertices than an edge will connect to. I want to be able to connect edge of one type to any vertex on any side.
2. For one vertex, I want to retrieve all connected vertices (depth 1) no matter the edge type.

For the requirement 1, an example would be a Tag vertex (to tag some entity with some information) and I want to be able to tag any vertex using i.e. HasTag edge in a named graph. From what I currently see is that I need to define the "From" collections ("To" collection is the Tag collection) and this is limited to 10 collections. Since I could have 100 or more From collections I don't see how to solve this with named graphs.

Option would be to use anonymous graphs but then I have a problem in the second requirement. I also want to have an option, when given a vertex, to find all connected vertices (depth = 1) no matter the type of an edge. In an anonymous graph I would need to specify all of the edge collections in a query and again, there could be 100 or more of them. I don't know if there is a limit to this number but I would assume there is one - maybe I'm mistaken since I haven't yet tried it out.

Has anyone any idea how to solve this with ArrangoDB? I really like the database but I would like it to be more "typeless", that is, that I wouldn't have to define the type of vertex collection an edge can connect to.

Best regards
Tomaz

Answer (score 0):

You can have more than 10 vertex collections in a named graph. The limitation of 10 only exists in the webUI. Creating the named graph over the ArangoShell or the server console will work.